# Client not receiving published events using demo code?

Tags: thruway

I'm trying out Thruway and am having trouble getting the demo code to work.

Javascript code:

```
<script src="https://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/autobahnjs/latest/autobahn.js"></script>
<script>
//    var autobahn = require('autobahn');

    var connection = new autobahn.Connection({url: 'ws://dev.mysite.com:9090/', realm: 'realm1'});

    connection.onopen = function (session) {

        // 1) subscribe to a topic
        function onevent(args) {
            console.log("Event:", args[0]);
        }
        session.subscribe('com.myapp.hello', onevent);

        // 2) publish an event
        session.publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world!']);
    };

    connection.open();
</script>
```

I have `SimpleWsServer.php` running:

```
<?php

require 'bootstrap.php';

use Thruway\Peer\Router;
use Thruway\Transport\RatchetTransportProvider;

$router = new Router();

$transportProvider = new RatchetTransportProvider("127.0.0.1", 9090);

$router->addTransportProvider($transportProvider);

$router->start();
```

I have `SimpleClient.php` running (I removed the RPC code since I only want to push messages from server to clients):

```
<?php

require 'bootstrap.php';

use Thruway\ClientSession;
use Thruway\Connection;

$onClose = function ($msg) {
    echo $msg;
};

$connection = new Connection(
    [
        "realm"   => 'realm1',
        "onClose" => $onClose,
        "url"     => 'ws://127.0.0.1:9090',
    ]
);

$connection->on(
    'open',
    function (ClientSession $session) {

        // 1) subscribe to a topic
        $onevent = function ($args) {
            echo "Event {$args[0]}\n";
        };
        $session->subscribe('com.myapp.hello', $onevent);

        // 2) publish an event
        $session->publish('com.myapp.hello', ['Hello, world from PHP!!!'], [], ["acknowledge" => true])->then(
            function () {
                echo "Publish Acknowledged!\n";
            },
            function ($error) {
                // publish failed
                echo "Publish Error {$error}\n";
            }
        );

//        // 3) register a procedure for remoting
//        $add2 = function ($args) {
//            return $args[0] + $args[1];
//        };
//        $session->register('com.myapp.add2', $add2);
//
//        // 4) call a remote procedure
//        $session->call('com.myapp.add2', [2, 3])->then(
//            function ($res) {
//                echo "Result: {$res}\n";
//            },
//            function ($error) {
//                echo "Call Error: {$error}\n";
//            }
//        );
    }

);

$connection->open();
```

It looks to me like the demo code sends the message `Hello, world from PHP!!!` to the client after it subscribes, but I'm not seeing a message in my browser's console.

I know the client is connecting to the server because `SimpleClient.php` outputs the following to the terminal:

```
2015-03-02T19:47:24.5464800 debug      [Thruway\Transport\PawlTransportProvider 13800] Received: [36,1574620859,33562629,{},["Hello, world!"]]
2015-03-02T19:47:24.5470880 debug      [Thruway\Peer\Client 13800] Client onMessage: [Thruway\Message\EventMessage]
Event Hello, world!
```

Am I missing something, or should `Hello, world from PHP!!!` have been printed out in the browser console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a post in a ticket in the github repo saying

> the publishing client will not receive the event message by default.

Opening another tab with the JS resulted in the message being sent to the previously opened tab.

Mystery solved!

Comment: That's right, by default the publishing client is excluded from receiving the message.  If you need to change this behavior, you can use the `exclude_me = false` option.  https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md#publisher-exclusion